# Running out of memory in Python using dict of namedtuples

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I have a set of questions that I'd like to be able to answer without having to use SQL to answer them. I was about 9 sub selects into a query when I decided that it's easier to do tree walks in Python.

Problem is when I try to get all of the data (3.2 billion rows) I care about into my machine in Python I run out of memory.

```
from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict

state_change = namedtuple("state_change", ["event", "phase", "datetime"])

sql = """
SELECT *
FROM job_history
WHERE job = 'job_name'"""

# Now we need to assosciate job states, and times.
jobs = defaultdict(list) # Key is the job id, list of state changes

for row in get_media_scan_data(sql):
    jobs[row[7]].append(state_change(
        row[8],
        row[10],
        row[5],))
```

an individual row looks like

```
datetime                job         job_id  event               impact_policy   phase
2000-06-10 08:44:04.000 job_name    4165    begin inode verify  NULL            4
```

One solution to this problem is doing my computation on a window of data. So say the first 200,000 rows, then doing 200,001 to 400,000, etc.

**Is there a more memory efficient way to store this data locally?** It would be a huge time saver if I could avoid having to redownload the dataset (using windows) multiple times.

Comment: 3.2 billion rows? haha, no.

Comment: You probably can't store it all in memory at once.  Where are you 'redownloading" it from?  Ideally you would download it once and store it in a database on your machine.

Comment: @wim Worth a shot. Another alternative is I have to learn how to more effectively program using SQL. Either case means a lot of time spent learning.

Comment: @BrenBarn It's from a internal SQL database so the bandwidth isn't necessarily a problem (other than lots of time).

Comment: `get_media_scan_data` probably returns an iterator (SQL cursor). You can load just 200,000 items from it by iterating it 200,000 times, `break`ing the iteration, processing the data and resuming iteration.

Comment: Just do the math: 3.2 bill. rows means `(3.2×bytes_per_row) GB` of RAM is needed.

Comment: _I was about 9 sub selects into a query_ - this sounds like you may have a problem that can approached by redesigning your data set. Perhaps it needs to be (de)normalized further. Even your database (assuming its running on the same machine) will have memory exhaustion problems and will be using its disk cache; you can find out by running a EXPLAIN (or similar) on the query. I think you should expand your question to give an idea of the kind of calculations you want to do.

Comment: @KlausD. Fair point. I'll leave this question up here as my shame.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid We totally need to rework how we store our data but that's a larger problem. The first problem I'm being asked is what's the wall time and execution time that our jobs are taking broken down by state. Each state change is recorded as a row in the database. Part of the problem is knowing when states mean the process is waiting vs computing which is why it kinda sucks to do in SQL.

Comment: You need map/reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With billions of rows, you obviously need some kind of disk persistence. Take a look at [bsddb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html) module, it's a very fast embedded key-value store.
A tiny example (notice a little weird way of storing values on python 3):

```
import bsddb3.db as db
def bsdtest():
    d = db.DB()
    d.open('test.db', dbtype=db.DB_HASH, flags=db.DB_CREATE)
    # d.exists()
    for key in range(1000000):
        d.put(bytes(str(key), encoding='ascii'), 
              bytes(str('value'), encoding='ascii'))
    d.close()
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I'll have to go back and give it a shot. I'm willing to be that even going out to disk (since I have several large SSD's) will be faster than pull it down chunks at a time from the remote DB.